# how can I make a new df column to contain a sequence based on other cols?

Tags: r

take my df:

```
feature <- c("a", "b", "c", "b", "a", "c", "a", "b", "c")
rank <- rep(1:length(unique(feature)), 3)
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(feature, rank))
```

I would like to a add a col `"run_des"`, based on the number of unique items in `feature`, i.e. the column should be like:

```
run_des <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)
```

but not hard-coded. So from the head, first `run_des` = 1, repeats 3x... so on until the end of the df.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `rep` :

```
df$run_des <- rep(seq(nrow(df)), each = 3, length.out = nrow(df))
```

Or

```
df$run_des <- ceiling(seq(nrow(df))/3)
df

#  feature rank run_des
#1       a    1       1
#2       b    2       1
#3       c    3       1
#4       b    1       2
#5       a    2       2
#6       c    3       2
#7       a    1       3
#8       b    2       3
#9       c    3       3
```

Comment: I am trying ```rep(1:length(unique(feature)), times=((nrow(df))/length(unique(df$feature))), each=length(unique(df$feature)))``` but do not understand why it does not work... will try with ```ceiling()```

Comment: thanks @RonakShah. This got it: ```df$run_des <- ceiling(seq(nrow(df))/length(unique(df$feature)))```

Comment: Ohh...so you want to create a unique index based on `feature` value? Maybe this would be better `df %>% group_by(feature) %>% mutate(row = row_number())` using `dplyr`.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `rowid`

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
df %>% 
     mutate(run_des = rowid(rank))
```

-output

```
#    feature rank run_des
#1       a    1       1
#2       b    2       1
#3       c    3       1
#4       b    1       2
#5       a    2       2
#6       c    3       2
#7       a    1       3
#8       b    2       3
#9       c    3       3
```